# How can we analyze a dataset with a pseudoreplication problem?

Tags: survival, experiment-design, independence, kaplan-meier, logrank-test

I am trying to analyse a data set with a pseudoreplication problem and would be grateful if someone could give me some guidelines on the best way to deal with it.

We have a set of subjects exposed to crossed treatments `Temperature` and `Light`, consisting of 4 and 5 levels, respectively (total of 20 conditions). In each condition, we monitored every individual daily for a given duration, looking for an irreversible change of their status (“inactive” -> “active” in our example). This is similar to survival data (“alive” to “dead”), so we thought Kaplan-Meier representations and Log-rank tests would be appropriate in our case.

However, we have faced unexpected issues during the experiment and had to optimize space in the climatic chambers, which caused a mix-up in the original plan: the 20 conditions are not replicated. Each of the 20 conditions corresponds to a separate box containing several individuals, but there is only one box per condition (20 boxes total). The conditions of `Temperature` and `Light` in each crossed condition were controlled continuously and confirmed to be reliable (with limited to no biases due to laboratory conditions).

To our knowledge, and from what we know of the study system, the status of individuals does not depend on the status of surrounding ones, and they are likely independent. However we have only one pool of individuals in each condition, with a ratio between “inactive” and “active” changing over time. We are not sure that statistical analyses for survival can be used without several groups of individuals per condition. Are there any workarounds for this situation? Alternatively, can we calculate the average duration until status change on all individuals in each box, and use that with tests for comparisons of means? If yes, how should we deal with individuals that did not change status during the monitoring period?

I will be pleased to give example data if required, though the issue is more about whether this pseudoreplication can be circumvented with a different approach, at the cost of statistical power.

Thanks in advance for the advice.